# What formula could calculate the speed of music playback in a variable length of time?

Tags: related-rates, music-theory

I am trying to create a patch in Max that records sound over a *portion* of a given length of time, then plays back the recording to fill out the *remaining portion* of time with the *speed* of playback adjusted, such that the complete recording of the first portion is heard within the second portion.

The total length is given as an integer of minutes 1-180.

I have a timer set up that records the length of the recording in milliseconds.

I converted the minutes to seconds by multiplying that number by 60, and the milliseconds to minutes by multiplying that number by .001 (please correct me if I have that wrong!)

I know I can determine the length of the playback (of the *remaining portion*) by subtracting the length of the recording (of the *first portion*) from the *total length*.

However, I don't know how to calculate the *speed* at which the recording needs to play in order to fill up the *remaining portion* of time. (I also don't know how to write this as math formulas).

Abstractly, I understand that the *speed* would be *less than 1* if the recorded portion takes *less than half* the total length. The *speed* would be *1* if the recorded portion is *exactly half* the total length. And, the *speed* would be *greater than 1* if the recorded portion is *more than half* the total length.

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

First please observe that *speed* refers to units of the type *something per unit of time*; for instance *kilometers per hour*, *liters per seconds*, etc. Here you are looking for an unit whose type is *seconds per seconds*, in which case I guess a more appropriate name would be a *speed ratio*

Let $T$ be the total length, $D$ the duration of the original recording, and $\lambda$ the *speed ratio* at which you want to play the recording the second time to fill the total duration.

So you basically have $T = D + \lambda D$. As you mentioned if $D = T/2$ then the second recording is played at the same speed as the first one, aka $\lambda=1$. By solving the above equation for $\lambda$ you find:

$$\lambda = (T-D)/D$$

Note that I have not mentioned the units of time (seconds, minutes etc.) but you need to make sure they all are in the same units.

Comment: Thank you! It works! I simply needed to add a step to divide 1/ to turn seconds per second into a playback speed.